# Overlaying one layer to another in html

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a html page with basically say with 2 divs. In the first div I have a login button which when clicked should open a overlaying kind of frame on the second div.

For example, you can see here https://beta.ryanair.com/gb/en/ that when myRyanair button is clicked a frame comes over second div and then when clicked again goes back.

I am new to html/angular and was trying a hands on a few things, please forgive me if sounding too naive.

Following is my html code:-

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" ng-app="musicPlayer">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>

   </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-js.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MusicPlayer as music">
<div id="div1">
    <first-tab></first-tab>
    <div ng-include="music.displayLoginPage()"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2" >

    Search Bar
</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Following is my js code:-

```
 var app=angular.module('musicPlayer',[]);


  app.controller('MusicPlayer',function(){
  var self=this;
  self.loginPageDisplay=0;
  self.setLoginPage=function(){
    if(self.loginPageDisplay === 0){
        self.loginPageDisplay=1;
    }
    else
    {
        self.loginPageDisplay=0;
    }
  }
  self.displayLoginPage=function(){
    if(self.loginPageDisplay===1){
        return 'loginPage.html';
    }
    return '';
   }
});

  app.directive('firstTab',function(){
   return{
    restrict:'E',
    controller:'MusicPlayer',
    controllerAs:'music',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl:'firstTab.html'
  }
})
```

Following is my firstTab.html which i using in directive

```
 <div>
   <div id="nameOfSite">
    <h1>GrooveHunt</h1>
   </div>
    <div class="loginKeys">
     <a href="" style="color: white" ng-click="music.setLoginPage()">Login</a>
    <a href="" style="color: white" id="signUp">Sign Up</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Following is loginpage.html which i inserted in the html when login is clicked

```
 <div id="loginPage">
  <div>
   Do u have liking for music sign up now?
   </div>
   <div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Following is the css :-

```
       #div1{
           height:10vh;
       background-color: darkblue;

       }
       #div2{
           height:60vh;
       background-color: white;
       }
       #div3{
           height:30vh;
       background-color: darkblue;
       }
       #nameOfSite{
           color: white;
           float: left;
           font-size:15px;
       }
       .loginKeys{
           margin-left:85%;
           font-size:22px;
       }
       #signUp{
           margin-left:20px;
       }
       #loginPage{
           border:2px solid darkblue;
           width: 100%;
           height:200px;
           background-color: red;
       }
```

Comment: provide us with some code here

Comment: You can achieve this by using z-index in css. Just be sure to set positions for your divs. Higher z-index = more to the front.

Comment: z-index seems to be working.. :)

Comment: If you need a more "fancy" solution just try https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal